# Filter many to many objects from parent queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models like this

```
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=256)
    y = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=256)

class B(models.Model):
    m = models.ManyToManyField(to=A, blank=True)
    #other fields

class C(models.Model):
    p = models.ManyToManyField(to=A, blank=True)
    #other fileds
```

now when i query the objects of model 'B' using
`query_b = models.B.objects.all()`

i want to exclude those objects from many to many queryset and not query_b objects 'm' if they exist in `models.C.objects.all()`  and return query_b

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let know ,

```
query_b = models.B.objects.all()
for instances in query_b:
    if(C.objects.filter(id=instances.id).exists()):
        query_b.remove(instances)
```

Now query_B will only have instances of B excluding C

Comment: That is very heavy with a lot of un necessary requests

Comment: i dont want to remove the objects of query_b i want to exclude the many to many objects of query_b

Comment: You can't and shouldn't do that, in a request, it would create an incomplete set of result which is compromising the integrity of the data (your query is not representing the real status of the data anymore)
You have to do that in the python code directly.

Comment: from the search I made, looks like there is no direct way you can filter (wheather if an object exist in another model) when making the query. what do you mean by exclude objects from m2m. you dint want those in the resultant queryset right ?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right - first query all possible `A` objects that are referred by `C`, then exclude them from your final query:

```py
queryset = models.C.objects.filter(p__isnull=False).values_list('p', flat=True).distinct()
query_b = models.B.objects.exclude(m__in=queryset)
```